# Negative sentence with do

Tags: present-tense

The positive sentence is:

> I do my homework at 6 pm.

However, is this negative version correct?

> I don't do my homework at 6 pm.

I'm confused about the double use of **do**.

Comment: Yes, that negative form is grammatically correct. "Do" is the same as any other verb. For example: "I fight crime for a living" vs. "I don't fight crime for a living."

Comment: The second _do_ is the Action _do_, as in _do the dishes/laundry/floor/work_, or _what to do about it_. It's a main (if idiomatic) verb. The first _do_ is _Do_-Support _do_, which has no meaning and gets stuck in when an auxiliary verb is needed (like with a negative or a question) but there isn't one there already. They're just two words that happen to sound the same, like _bare bear_.

Comment: @JohnLawler as in "You don't do your homework at 6 pm do you, are you just lying?"  "I *do* do my homework at 6 pm!".

Comment: The emphatic stressed _do_ is yet another special form. The little words are the hard words; they're all tangled up in idioms and grammar gears.

Comment: @JohnLawler Emphatic _do_ is the same as _Do_-Support _do_, surely. Emphasis is simply another case that requires an auxiliary: the same verbs that don't use _Do_-Support for negation and questions also don't for emphasis.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I do believe you're right. _Do_-Support _do_ is unstressed unless contracted, whereas emphatic _do_ is always stressed, so they could be viewed as variants. I'm not sure which verbs you're referring to; the only verbs that don't use _Do_-Support are auxiliary verbs, and they get contrastively stressed. The only strange thing beside stress about contrastive _do_ is that it can occur without negation, contraction, or inversion to require it, as in _I do believe you're right._

Comment: _Do_- support has three uses: (1) primary verb negation as in "That seems reasonable" ~ "That doesn't seem reasonable"; (2) sub-aux inversion as in "She speaks English" ~ "Does she speak English"? and (3) emphatic polarity as in "She moved the picture" ~ "She DID move the picture". Emphatic polarity can only be applied to aux verbs.

Answer (score 1):

It's correct.

If you use a plain *do* negatively, or in a question, you throw in another *do*.

> I do hair and nails.
>
> I don't do hair or nails.
>
> Do you do hair or nails?

If *do* is being used as a helping verb, e.g. emphatically, then you don't add another *do* when negating it.

> I did walk to the park yesterday.
>
> I did not walk to the park yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

**I do my homework at 6 pm.**

**I don't do my homework at 6 pm.**

compare to:

**I am generally doing my homework at 6 pm.**

**I am generally not doing my homework at 6 pm.**

--

You could also say:

**(But)I do do my homework at 6 pm.**

--> if you want to emphasize the fact that you actually are doing it; for example if somebody accuses you of not doing it. But if you just want to point out the fact that you are doing it at 6 without highlighting it, you can save some time by dropping one of the do's

**I do not do my homework at 6 pm.**